# "Unsupported data format" while running tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, amd-gpu

I am new to TensorFlow. I have recently installed it (Windows CPU version, AMD FX-8350, eight cores).
The installation went fine.

I received the following message when I’m trying to run a simple script:

```
Non‑OK‑status: 
Status(error::Code::INVALID_ARGUMENT, "Unsupported data format") 
status: Invalid argument: Unsupported data format
```

The error occurs when I’m fitting a CNN model at the 2nd epoch.

Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Can you show us your code and give more information on how you installed TensorFlow?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a bug in TensorFlow ([GitHub Issue #17945](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17945)), which has been fixed in version 1.11.